# Right format in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Hi can any one help me write this htaccess code for the url mentioned below.
my url is soemthing like this http://localhost/worldofcontrol/search/ic3500a192c
and i want this to be changed to http://localhost/worldofcontrol/ic3500a192c
and my htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ search/product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: like can u help me with the code. like how to write

Comment: redirect the url

Comment: actually i need it for multiple htaccess multiple i tried this and it did not work so i had to create one more folder in which i have written the above code. th e multiple htaccess was something like this.

Comment: RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product_details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: no it did not so i have created new folder search

Comment: and i want to exclude that search and display it in url.

Comment: for seo purpose